# INotifyPropertyChanged in singleton and binding to the WPF element

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm bit experimenting with MVVM once again and I'm currently experiencing two issues with my code. 
First let me explain the code structure:

I have a class like this (simplified of course):

```
public abstract class NavigationServiceBase : NotifyPropertyChangedBase, INavigationService
{
   private IView _currentView;
   public IView CurrentView
   {
       get { return _currentView; }
       protected set
       {
           _currentView = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
       }
   }

   public virtual void DoSomethingFancy()
   { 
       CurrentView = ...; // here I expect it to fire OnPropertyChanged and notify my View
   }
}
```

And the singleton inheriting from this base class:

```
public class NavigationService : NavigationServiceBase
{
    private static readonly INavigationService _instance = new NavigationService();
    public static INavigationService Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    ...
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private INavigationService _navigationService;

public IView CurrentView { get { return _navigationService.CurrentView; } }
public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    _navigationService = NavigationService.Instance;
    NavigateCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Navigate(param));
}

private void Navigate(object requestedPage)
{
    _navigationService.Navigate((string)requestedPage);
    //OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView"); // this works , but...
}
```

Now the issues:
1.) I'm editing the XAML in Visual Studio 2012 Express. It seems it works, but I get a warning with this message: `Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions for more information.` It shows in the part when I declare the Resources for the binding the ViewModel. What does it mean? If I get rid of the singleton, the message goes away. Project compiles and runs just fine either way.

2.) it seems my OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView") isn't firing or something, because I have to manually call this method from within the ViewModel itself. If I try it from the base class or from the inheriting singleton, it doesn't work. (binding just ignores the new values). If I do this manually while handing the command, it works. Yes, it's just an extra line of code, but I wonder, is there a way to make it work without "cheating" like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're binding to the property in your ViewModel:

```
public IView CurrentView { get { return _navigationService.CurrentView; } }
```

The `NatigationService` is raising `PropertyChanged`, but this happens in `_navigationService`, not in the ViewModel itself, so the View never sees the event.

There are two common options -

You can listen for the `PropertyChanged` event on your navigation service, and handle raising it locally if needed:

```
_navigationService = NavigationService.Instance;
_navigationService.PropertyChanged += (o,e) => 
{
   // When navigation raises prop changed for this property, raise it too
   if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentView")
     OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
}; 
NavigateCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Navigate(param));
```

The other alternative is to expose the service, and bind directly to it:

```
public INavigationService Navigation { get { return _navigationService; } }
```

Then, in your View, bind to the content inside of the service instead of a local property:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Navigation.CurrentView}" />
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense :) Thank you. I figured out the cause of the first "issue" by myself, obviously it was just a silly thing. I was trying to do some reflection in the constructor, trying to inspect the current assembly, which obviously fails during designing the application.....